Installation of platform-tools without calling `cargo build-sbf`
I'm fixing the solana-validator package on Nix in this PR, and I want cargo build-bpf and cargo build-sbf to work. Right now when I try to run them, they try to download the platform-tools to the Nix store, which is a permission error. If I could install the platform-tools during the package process, under $out/bin/sdk/sbf, I could use the system properly. What is exactly the link to install it and where do I put it?

It's a bit tricky because there's a few different concepts.
First you have the SDK, which is typically bundled at /home/$USER/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin. These contain Solana-specific tooling.
Then the SDK uses the platform-tools, which contain the Rust compiler and LLVM forks for building Solana programs, which are typically stored at /home/$USER/.cache/solana/<VERSION>/platform-tools.
cargo build-sbf hardcodes a particular version of the platform tools, but you could make this work by downloading the platform-tools to the cache directory and then the SDK to the proper directory before running cargo build-sbf.
If you get stuck anywhere, your best bet is to read through the source code for cargo build-sbf. For example, here's the default sdk dir at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/4bc8d5d7a15b7e44803bbe7eb33bc6455aaa4ada/sdk/cargo-build-sbf/src/main.rs#L50-56:
            env::current_exe()
                .expect("Unable to get current executable")
                .parent()
                .expect("Unable to get parent directory")
                .to_path_buf()
                .join("sdk")
                .join("sbf"),

As for the SDK, that's installed with agave-install. Here's the code that figures out where to download the SDK release: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/4bc8d5d7a15b7e44803bbe7eb33bc6455aaa4ada/install/src/command.rs#L569-L575:
    format!(
        "https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/releases/download/v{}/solana-release-{}.tar.bz2",
        release_semver,
        crate::build_env::TARGET
    )


I think I managed to install the SDK, so the question that remained was the platform-tools. I've seen it downloads to the cache directory, but after that it tries to do something that requires root permission. I'll investigate the cargo-build-sbf code, thanks.

Hm, that's strange, maybe it's the link_solana_toolchain step? https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/ae18213c19ea5335dfc75e6b6116def0f0910aff/sdk/cargo-build-sbf/src/main.rs#L479
